# How to set title name of the pdf. While viewing the Document(New Tab)

Tags: php, laravel

> How can we change the title name of the pdf. While viewing the Document

**[image: Note:]**

> I didnt use any
>   controller are modal, I just pass the url in href tag, But I want to
>   change the title name

```
<a target="_blank" @if($docDet[$csr['docid']]['docext'] == 'pdf') href="{{url($csr['docpath'])}}" @else href="{{url(ADMIN.'/downloaddoc/'.$docDet[$csr['docid']]['dockey'])}}" @endif class="icon-btn blue-btn" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="View"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
```

Comment: As the Browser itself is parses the PDF, you cannot modify the page title directly. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27653004/7008354). (updated to better explanation)

Comment: Thanks Let me check

Comment: But How can I add the meta tag in href

Comment: If you are no using a library to create / modify the PDF; then [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44644580/7008354) might be what you want to do.

Comment: Yeah sir I understand that, I just view the pdf, I dont want user to create or edit pdf, Instead of that I just want to rename the page title

Comment: If you don't want to modify the pdf then it is not possible to change the title displayed in the Browser.

Comment: Oh any other idea sir,

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that to set the title, the title must set into the pdf, but there is a workaround ( see explanation )

**Explanation**:

The page with target "_blank" attribute, set the file names base on the last part of the url. So if the url is my.site/32/55 , the html title is 55.

**The workaround is to set the file name as the last part of the url**

**1) Web.php**

This is the most important part. To give the page the pdf title, set

```
Route::get('/pdfSee/{fileID}/{htmlTitle}', 'FileController@viewInTheBrowser')->name('file.see');
```

2) **Controller**

```
public function viewInTheBrowser(File $file){
$basePath = 'public/myFolder/'; 
        return  response()->download(storage_path("app/".$this->basePath. $file->file_system_path), $file->file_name, [], 'inline');
    }
```

3) View

```
<a href="{{ URL::route('file.see', [$file, $file->file_name]) }}" target="_blank"> Download </a>
```

**As you can see, we pass in the route file.see the actual file name as last param, so wen the html page is open, it takes the last param ( the file name ) as html page title**