# How to set title for pdf file opening in new tab (_blank) in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my try, were it opened on newtab, But its always showing **test pdf** as title

```
function titlepath(path,name){
    alert(path);
    alert(name);
    document.title = name;
    window.open(path, '_blank');
}
```

Comment: You are trying to set the title of the document this JS code is in here, you are not even accessing the popup window …

Comment: `document.title` refers to the window you're in _now_, not the one you're opening, Even then I'm not sure it'll work, since a PDF is not a HTML document, so you can't set its title. Javascript can only affect HTML documents. The browser is just displaying a file, so it'll use the name of the file

Comment: You would have to use an HTML document, and display the PDF in an `<iframe>`

Comment: Sorry sir, Then how to do sir?

Comment: @ChrisG But I dont want to do in <iframe>

Comment: Read my edited comment above, I don't think this is possible. You're outside the realms of a HTML document when you do this, so you can't use JS to affect what happens. It's just part of the browser's functionality, it's not part of your web page anymore.

Comment: @ADyson Any chance to do it sir, Except <iframe>

Comment: Like I said twice already, I don't think so. However, I searched a little, I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37299858/5947043 but I don't know if it actually works or not, you can try it, or search some more (I googled for "window.open set title")

Comment: Thanks and let me check

Comment: Just saw, you asked this yesterday already - https://stackoverflow.com/q/50737670/1427878 Please stop creating multiple questions about the same issue.

Comment: sure sir, But yesterday I tried in php, Now I tried in jquery

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set title name of the pdf. While viewing the Document(New Tab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50737670/how-to-set-title-name-of-the-pdf-while-viewing-the-documentnew-tab)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution works for me. 
**Question: How to change the title of pdf in newly opened tab**

```
     function titlepath(path,name){

        //In this path defined as your pdf url and name (your pdf name)

            var prntWin = window.open();
            prntWin.document.write("<html><head><title>"+name+"</title></head><body>"
                + '<embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src="'+ path+ '" '
                + 'type="application/pdf" internalinstanceid="21"></body></html>');
            prntWin.document.close();
        }
```

Comment: This sets the title of the new tab/window, but not the file.

Comment: I clearly mentioned as browser title opening in a new tab @Kostiantyn

Comment: Please suggest how to change default pdf fileName when open in new page.

Comment: I see the title was changed, but the path (I mean the address bar) shows blank still. How could I resolve this ?